Does getting residence permit in another EU member state cancel German Niederlassungserlaubnis?
I possess a § 18c AufenthG Niederlassungserlaubnis in Germany.
As far as I understand, it expires only if I leave Germany for more than 6 months at once.
I intend to obtain a residence permit in Cyprus (family reunion), which is an EU member state, but not a Schengen country.
If I get a residence permit in Cyprus and then reside there for approximately 5 months in a row, then go back to Germany for a few days and then back to Cyprus for 5 months again, etc.
Will it allow me to keep my German Niederlassungserlaubnis?
P. S.:
I plan on continue renting my apartment in Germany and working remotely for a German company, so paying my taxes in Germany.
Also, I have applied for German citizenship and plan to live permanently in Germany after a few years.


If you’re married to a German, your PR never expires (even if you’re staying more than 6 consecutive months abroad), unless Germany doesn’t like you anymore (e. g. you’re acting/behaving anti-democratically), § 51 Ⅱ 2 AufenthG.
If you have legally stayed in Germany for more than 15 years in total, your PR never expires (even if you’re staying more than 6 consecutive months abroad) provided that you can make a living and Germany still likes you (e. g. you’re not a dangerous criminal), § 51 Ⅱ 1 AufenthG.
Otherwise:

If you’re apparently leaving Germany for good, your PR expires immediately, § 51 Ⅰ main cl. 1 no. 6 AufenthG.
There is no established definition as to what constitutes a non‑transient departure though.
According to case law all circumstances need to be considered, the emphasis being on objective circumstances though.
This includes but is not limited to

the duration of the stay abroad (longer duration indicates stronger intent to leave Germany permanently),
the purpose of the stay abroad (does the purpose require just a short‑term/temporary stay, or is it indefinite in kind),
the strength of ties with Germany or the home country (e. g. family ties),
whether employment in Germany has been left,
whether an apartment/house in Germany is maintained,
whether you have deregistered with the Einwohnermeldeamt,
whether you are taking/sending all your personal belongings to the next destination,
whether you are taking care of next of kin in need of care, or
whether you have been accused of a crime and might be fleeing from prosecution.

Your personal, subjective intention can be (and is) taken into account, too, but is non‑decisive.
Important:
This assessment is primarily done at the point of time of your departure.
For instance if you get stuck abroad because you were hospitalized, this does not indicate an intent to permanently leave Germany.
The burden of proof for an expiration according to § 51 Ⅰ main cl. 1 no. 6 AufenthG is with the immigration authorities, the burden of proof against is with you.

If none of the above applies, you simply have to re-enter Germany within 6 months, § 51 Ⅰ main cl. 1 no. 7 AufenthG.
This period can be extended if it’s in the interest of Germany (e. g. you’re a researcher heading to an Antarctic expedition).
There’s no set minimum number of days you have to stay in Germany, you can stay even zero days.
It just needs to be believable that you still intend to use the PR.
It may be argued that obtaining a residence permit in Cyprus, or even the mere application for a residence permit can be deemed an objective clue that you did not intend to use your German PR again (i. e. a § 51 Ⅰ main cl. 1 no. 6 situation).
On the other hand maintaining your apartment and keeping your job are clues for your return.
The petition for naturalization, however, is actually kind of evidence against using your PR since German citizens do not need no permission to stay (only foreigners do).



Keep in mind, other reasons for revoking your PR still apply, e. g. if you are about to be deported, § 53 AufenthG.
This will immediately expire your PR, too.


Thank you for a very good answer, though it is essentially a slightly improved version of "It's complicated", I can better see now why it is so complicated indeed. I guess I better stay in Germany until I get citizenship

(+1) Are there cases where the application of a residence permit led to the loss of a Niederlassungserlaubnis? This sounds like an incredibly restrictive reading of § 51 Ⅰ no. 6.

@Relaxed It is a consideration that needs to be taken account of. Considering § 51 Ⅰ no. 8 AufenthG the mere application of asylum terminates certain permissions to stay, so it is not unheard of that filing an application has secondary consequences. However, in Igor’s case there are a couple other (objective) clues he intends to keep using his Niederlassungserlaubnis. It is not for us to say how German authorities decide in his case though.
